# Changing text color and style in material-ui version 0.15.4

Tags: css, material-ui

I am fairly new to CSS and front end web development and having trouble in setting style of the button on my page. I want to change the text color of it and maybe change the primary color of my theme as well (currently it looks cyan, i want to make it blue). I know material-ui has moved to inline styles and i tried passing style as a variable to the "style" field in the button, but wasn't able to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var React = require('react'),
mui = require('material-ui'),
LoginDialog = require('./login-dialog.jsx'),
RaisedButton = mui.RaisedButton,
MuiThemeProvider = require('material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'),
darkBaseTheme = require('material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme');

var Index = React.createClass({
  getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme),
    };
  },
  childContextTypes: {
    muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="mui-app-canvas home-page-background">
        <RaisedButton
          className="login-button"
          label="Login"
          onTouchTap={ this._handleLoginDialog }
          linkButton={ false } />
        <LoginDialog
          ref="loginDialog"
          loginUrl={ this.props.loginUrl } />
      </div>
    )
  },

  _handleLoginDialog: function() {
    this.refs.loginDialog.show();
  }
});

module.exports = Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to edit the style in material ui is to edit or write your own theme.

Here you can see already implemented themes:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/src/styles/baseThemes

And here all editable properties:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js

And here how to implement it:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! When i try to implement the example, I am getting the following error "MuiThemeProvider.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.". Without nesting the component in MuiThemeProvider it works fine.

Comment: can you show bit code, how you implemented it? seems you try to mount multiple components in the provider